# loading a simple semi transparent PNG in Windows Mobile using C#

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, png, alphablending

I am new to Windows Mobile programming. I want to load a PNG file which has an Alpha Channel. After 2 days of searching in Internet, I am still at square 1. Can someone help me? I got an example which uses uses a wrapper to access the AlphaBlend API. But when I set the AC_SRC_ALPHA flag in BlendingFunction, it does not draw anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've use the [WindowslessControls library from Koushik Dutta](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2008/12/windowlesscontrols-tutorial-part-2.html) for using PNGs with an alpha channel and have found it great.

You may also want to look try [Alpha Mobile Controls](http://www.codeplex.com/alphamobilecontrols).